# Css3 evaluatable expressions?

Tags: javascript, css

Are there any techniques that allow for expressions in css3 statements?

Frequently it is helpful to do such things as `width: 35%+20px` or similar. Right now the only solutions I have to these circumstances are to either redesign the page or to use javascript to dynamically set the css.

Comment: Due to the similarity of answers, I accepted the oldest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS working draft on values and units specifies a [calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-css3-values-20060919/#calc) function, though it is only [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) in the latest versions of IE and Firefox.

Comment: Remember to state the current version number in your answers, calc is apparently supported in IE9+ (2 versions old now), FF4+ and Chrome19+ http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: A reasonable point. Although everything is dated, it's too often difficult to correlate a date with a specific version of a specification.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately [CSS3 calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) is not quite ready yet ;)

Quote from the specs:

```
section {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em; border: solid 1px;
  width: calc(100%/3 - 2*1em - 2*1px);
}

p {
  margin: calc(1rem - 2px) calc(1rem - 1px);
  border: solid transparent; border-width: 2px 1px;
}

p:hover { border-color: yellow; }
```

while it's scary that evaluation expressions may be allowed in CSS (it's not a programming language) it's exciting that something as simple as "take-away" might be used.. but then again there is the "[box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)" property, so perhaps it's not necessary - to do otherwise is perhaps losing the **KISS** principle?

Comment: But not allowing it is going to be very detrimental to simplicity from a user's (css developer) standpoint. Adding it is breaking simplicity on language design standpoint and making css something it's not. Dilemma dilemma dilemma...

Comment: @Razor Storm.. no I don't think so (and I've been a CSS developer for a wee while now), allowing it will bring the "jQuery (or javascript for those that prefer) maths" can fix it mentality. It is just another (I can count) solution and will always be preferred over understanding the language itself. Adding maths to any solution will not be "simple" CSS, you either do design or maths don't you? - CSS is a design and layout choice, what that has to do with counting, I don't know and I'm really not convinced that I would "grok" CSS if I applied just my maths knowledge!

Comment: As far as it is a layout tool, I agree with. However, there does arise circumstances where calculations becomes necessary. (You want a div to take up half the size of a larger div, but also to make some room for a small 100 pixel wide div. width: 50%-100px;

Comment: @Razor I think we're agreed really, not allowing it will be detrimental, but allowing it will remove the simplicity as you say.. Dilemma indeed!

Answer (score 1):

The calc() function can be used wherever length values are allowed.  This is defined in CSS3 Values and Units (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/).  I don't know what browser are supporting it.

```
section {
   float: left;
   margin: 1em; border: solid 1px;
   width: calc(100%/3 - 2*1em - 2*1px);
}

p {
   margin: calc(1rem - 2px) calc(1rem - 1px);
   border: solid transparent; border-width: 2px 1px;
}
p:hover { border-color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[dicejs.com](http://dicejs.com) (supposedly stands for dynamically injected css engine) A client-side version of SASS. Pretty slick and allows real time manipulation of variables and functions. The plugins are rudimentary for colors and CSS3 but you could easily write your own because it's all in javascript. I think this is a nice way to get around waiting for CSS specifications to be supported in major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's called Sass.

http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: I love Sass/SCSS, but it doesn't improve CSS, despite the wild acclaim, it doesn't make those calculations for you, you need to know that those calculations need to be made and how to ask Sass/SCSS to do them for you!

Comment: Sass is compiled, and even though you can do calculations, you can not do dynamic calculation (for example, when the viewport changes), this is not possible without "CSS3 calc"/javascript