# Size a div by height of the browser

Tags: css, height, css-position

How can I make a div be the height of the browser - 40px?

If that is easy, how can I make a div be (height of the browser) - (how far down the element begins on the page) - (40px)?

CSS only is ideal. Doing this in javascript is easy, but we all know that is bad form :)

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @watson unfortunately no Less please. But it's just compiled into CSS anyway, so if you can write it in Less you can copy the CSS :)

Comment: @cimmanon - I have a scrollable list that I'd like to take size using as much space as possible. But it's not at the top of my page.

Comment: @DonnyP A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207447/css3-evaluatable-expressions

Have you checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding on the bottom:

```
selector {
   position:absolute;
   ....
   height:100%;
   padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

Comment: Won't this cause weirdness if there's a background involved?

Comment: This makes the page extend beyond the browser window, not usually what you want with `height: 100%;` http://jsbin.com/efaqok/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

I don't think there is any way to get the 'how far down the page the element begins' info without JS.

Answer (score 0):

[Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
}

div#right{
  height:100%
}
```

And than you can add some padding.